# How to get the name of the folder on sharepoint if I have the sharepoint link to the folder using Power automate flow

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, power-automate

How to get a sharepoint folder name if I have the sharepoint link to the folder using Power automate flow.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for? The **Folder Path** property in the **Get folder metadata using path** action is the site relative path.

[image: Power Automate flow]